# Backbone.js save method drops some of the model's attributes on PUT/POST to the server

Tags: backbone.js, attributes, ruby-on-rails-3.2, server-side

When saving a specific backbone model, I notice that one of the fields is missing when I inspect the PUT request on the server. I have this model:

```
App.Models.User = Backbone.Model.extend({

    name: "user",

    url: function() {
        u = "/users"
        if ( this.id ) {
            u += "/" + this.id;
        }
        return u;
    }
});

App.Collections.Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    urlRoot: "/users",
    model: App.Models.User
});
```

And I save it on View like so:

```
App.Views.EditUserForm = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "submit": "saveUser"
    },


    saveUser: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var _id  =  this.$("#user_id").val(); 
        var data = {
            id:         ( _id !== '' ) ? _id : null,
            first_name: this.$("#user_first_name").val(),
            last_name:  this.$("#user_last_name").val(),
            email:      this.$("#user_email").val(),
            bio:        this.$("#user_bio").val()
        };

        var _this = this;
        var user  = new App.Models.User();

        // This will create or update a user 
        // record on the server
        user.save(data,{
            success: _this.handleSuccess,
            error:   _this.handleErrors
        });
    },

    handleSuccess: function(user, resp) { /* ... */ },
    handleErrors:  function(user, resp) { /* ... */ }
});
```

However, when I get to the server side (Rails), the `bio` field isn't in the request's params:

```
(debugger) params[:user].keys
[ "first_name", "last_name", "email" ]
```

That `bio` field is allowed to be null, but using the client side debugger I can see that it has a value in the `data = {...}` object right before being sent to the save method.

```
> data.bio
"something, somthing, dark side"
```

I can also see that when I use the collection to fetch an existing object on the server, that field is available and populated. Only the 'model.save()' method is dropping that value somewhere along the way. Any ideas why? thanks.

---

## UPDATE -

I can see that the `bio` field was sent to the server, but it's not under `params[:user]` but rather at the root of the params hash:

```
(debugger) ap params
{
        "id"         => "1",
        "first_name" => "John",
        "last_name"  => "Doe",
        "email"      => "john@bleh.com",
        "bio"        => "something, somthing, dark side",
        "user"       => {
                "first_name" => "John",
                "last_name"  => "Doe",
                "email"      => "john@bleh.com",
        },
        "controller" => "users",
        "action"     => "update"
}
```

What determines what goes under params[:user]*?

* Sorry if this is turning to be more of a rails question than backbone.

Answer (score 2):

Got it!

Turns that only the attributes you mark as `attr_accessible` in the `ActiveRecord::Base` model will be added to the nested model's params when you update or create. Previously I had

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email
end
```

And therefore, the `params[:user]` contained only those fields allowed for mass assignment - `:first_name`, `:last_name` and `:email`. Adding `:bio` to that list solved the issue, enabling me to use `@user.update_attributes(params[:user])` in my controller's `update` action.

So this isn't a Backbone issue, just Rails configuration.